# IO error: seeking to local header : while reading from a remote server using Archive::Zip,PERL

Tags: perl, ioerror

Want to read the contents from a .csv file which is in a remote zip file without downloading & extracting the zip file to local machine.

I need this because the file zip file size is too large and downloading it whenever needed 
takes longer time.

I am trying this in perl.

My code is :
my $ftp = Net::FTP::AutoReconnect->new("ftp.somename.com");
    $ftp->login("user","password");
    $ftp->cwd("path");

```
my $fh = Net::FTP::RetrHandle->new($ftp,"filename.zip");
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($fh);
my @member_names = $zip->memberNames();
my $member1 =  $zip->memberNamed("Basic/BoardDescriptions.csv");

my $string = $member1->contents();
print Dumper $string;
```

I get io::seeking to local header error while calling contents method,
till that statement i guess the code is working fine.

Thanks in advance to any one who gives a try to it.
Thanks.

Comment: NET::FTP will "download the file to a local machine". You can't read a file remotely without having something running on that remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not Archive::ZIP 's fault .. 
can you print @member_names ?

It's not obvious how your'e suppose to extract an individual file, although [Net::FTP::RetrHandle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aFTP%3a%3aRetrHandle) does promise it:

> This was originally designed for use with Archive::Zip; it's reliable enough that the table of contents and individual files can be extracted from a remote ZIP archive without downloading the whole thing.

Try doing the same with another file from another server..